# Sending Email attachment using django :

Tags: python, django, email, sendmail

i am trying to attach file and send it to email . 
but it is redirecting me to an error page i.e. error.html. File is not getting send to email. Can u plz help me with this error . I am a newbie in django, your help be appreciated. ThankYou

## models.py

```
class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attach = models.FileField()
    message = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Email
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ['email', 'attach','subject' ,'message']


    def _clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        return email


    def _clean_subject(self):
        subject = self.cleaned_data.get('subject')
        return subject


    def _clean_message(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data.get('message')
        return message

    def _clean_attach(self):
        attach = self.cleaned_data.get('attach')
        return attach
```

## views.py

```
def send_email(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EmailForm()
      context = {
            "form": form
        }
        return render(request,'email.html', context)

    form = EmailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data.get("subject")
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        email   = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        a  = request.FILES['attach']
        try:


            mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, 'vamagithub@gmail.com')
            mail.attach_file(a.name, a.read(), a.content_type)
            mail.send()
            context ={
                "message": 'Sent email to %s' % email
            }
            return render(request,'email.html',context)

        except:
            context = {
                "message": 'Either the attachment is too  big or corrupt'
            }
            return render(request,'error.html',context)

        return render(request,'email.html', {'message': 'Unable to send email. Please try again later'})
```

Comment: Remove the except block to see the actual error.

Comment: it is going back to email.html page

Answer (score 0):

You have used attach_file. In that you have to provide path of the file for passing these parameters a.name, a.read(), a.content_type. You use only attach(a.name, a.read(), a.content_type). For more information, read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)